# Different screen.width/height and pixel ratio in PHP vs. JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

**CODE**

**javascript**

```
<html>
<body>
<script>document.write(window.screen.width);</script>
<script>document.write(window.screen.height);</script>
<script>document.write(window.devicePixelRatio);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**php**

```
<?php
echo '<script>document.write(window.screen.width);</script> ';
echo '<script>document.write(window.screen.height);</script> ';
echo '<script>document.write(window.devicePixelRatio);</script>';
```

**RESULTS**

**javascript:**

```
1920 1200 1
```

**php:**

```
1760 1100 1.0909090909090908
```

why can there be a different between?!
of course, it is the same browser/same window

Comment: PHP is executed before reaching browser `window`, correct?

Comment: yes, i guess so but what window is it then?

Comment: Are you trying to code locally?

Comment: yes it is locally

Comment: u're right - it works when i upload it to a provider

Comment: the question is now: why is there a difference on my local machine

Comment: at least you helped me :) tnx guest271314

Comment: Well... hrmpf. I decided to take both your examples, and put them in a file and try each one in my Chrome, and Safari. Both browsers output `1920 1200 1` with both versions you have posted. I cannot seem to reproduce the issue.

Comment: then you have to try it locally (maybe a problem with WAMP?)